# mysql query very slow when adding subquery

Tags: mysql

I have below query , only 800 record taking  5 minits to run, can you some help please

```
SELECT 

vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid,vtiger_salesorder.salesorder_no,vtiger_salesorder.sostatus,
(SELECT se.s_date
FROM
softMax_events as se 
INNER JOIN vtiger_salesorder as bm ON bm.salesorderid = se.orderNum
where (bm.sostatus = 'Order' AND se.orderNum = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid) AND se.appointTyp='60'
group by bm.salesorderid  Limit 0,1) As sdate

FROM
  vtiger_salesorder
Inner Join vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
WHERE (vtiger_salesorder.sostatus = 'Order')
and ( vtiger_crmentity.deleted<>'1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, hope so this will help you,

```
SELECT vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid,vtiger_salesorder.salesorder_no,vtiger_salesorder.sostatus,se.s_date
    FROM  vtiger_salesorder 
    Inner Join vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
    INNER JOIN softMax_events se ON se.orderNum = salesorderid 
    WHERE (vtiger_salesorder.sostatus = 'Order') AND/OR
    se.orderNum = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid AND se.appointTyp='60'
    and ( vtiger_crmentity.deleted<>'1')
```

**Edit:**
I noticed that there is some relation between `vtiger_salesorder and softMax_events`  and you can use a join for both table, and in this way you can remove that inner query, i tried it you may test it. this will help you for sure after a bit modification.

Comment: hi zzzz, u r great... thansk